# Angular2 Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

In Angular2 I can create a typeahead field looking at a datasource using ng2-bootstrap like this:

```
<input [typeahead]="dataSource.listOfObjects" ... />
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a conditional value that decides if an item is included in the typeahead?

For instance, it may look like:

```
<input [typeahead]="dataSource.listOfObjects where include == true" ... />
```

Comment: Just filter the array in your component: `includedObjects = list.filter(e => e.include);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pipe (in Angular 1 its called as filter) and process your data along with `ng2-bootstrap`.

Another way is the make a function in your component which will return filtered data to use in your typeahead.

```
<input [typeahead]="functionInYourComponnet()" ... />


export class DataComopnent() {

  functionInYourComponnet() {
  ...
  ...
  return filteredData;
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the function as it was quicker to set up. The data is in a service and is also used by a second component that needs to see each entry, including those filtered on the typeahead.